# Can't access variable in function

Tags: javascript

Javascript noob here. I'm having a problem with the variable "meal", which can't be accessed for some reason. I returned it from the getMealById() function so i thought that would make it accessible in another function but somehow i can't access that variable.**(last 2 lines of code)**. If anyone sees what i'm doing wrong, i would gladly appreciate your help. I've been awake till 6am yesterday trying to find it without success. I came here because i don't know where else to ask now. Thanks in advance!

```
const meals = document.getElementById("meals");

getRandomMeal();
fetchFavMeals();

async function getRandomMeal() {
  const resp = await fetch(
    "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php"
  );

  const respData = await resp.json();
  const randomMeal = respData.meals[0];

  addMeal(randomMeal, true);
}

async function getMealById(id) {
  const resp = await fetch(
    "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=" + id
  );

  const respData = await resp.json();

  const meal = respData.meals[0];

  return meal;
}

async function getMealBySearch(term) {
  const meals = await fetch(
    "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=" + term
  );
}

function addMeal(mealData, random = false) {
  console.log(mealData);
  const meal = document.createElement("div");
  meal.classList.add("meal");

  meal.innerHTML = `
  <div class="meal-header">
    ${random ? `<span class="random">Random Recipe</span>` : ""}
    <img
    src="${mealData.strMealThumb}"
    alt="${mealData.strMeal}"
  />
  </div>
  <div class="meal-body">
    <h4>${mealData.strMeal}</h4>
    <button class="fav-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    </button>
  </div>`;

  const btn = meal.querySelector(".meal-body .fav-btn");

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (btn.classList.contains("active")) {
      removeMealLS(mealData.idMeal);
      btn.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      addMealLS(mealData.idMeal);
      btn.classList.add("active");
    }
  });

  meals.appendChild(meal);
}

function addMealLS(mealId) {
  const mealIds = getMealsLS();
  localStorage.setItem("mealIds", JSON.stringify([...mealIds, mealId]));
}

function removeMealLS(mealId) {
  const mealIds = getMealsLS();

  localStorage.setItem(
    "mealIds",
    JSON.stringify(mealIds.filter((id) => id !== mealId))
  );
}

function getMealsLS() {
  const mealIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mealIds"));
  return mealIds === null ? [] : mealIds;
}

async function fetchFavMeals() {
  const mealIds = getMealsLS();

  const meals = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < mealIds.length; i++) {
    const mealId = mealIds[i];

    meal = await getMealById(mealId);

    meals.push(meal);
  }
}
```

Comment: put `let meal;` outside your `getMealById` function and inside your function do `meal =  meal` - then you should be able to access it. consdering you are using `await` for it for the data to be assigned to meal variable - that would make it global and your will be able access it later as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the variable declaration in the `fetchFavMeals` function for variable `meal`. Just use let or const for it. After that you will be able to access.

Comment: The thing is , iget the error: Could not find name 'meal'. Did you mean 'meals'.ts(2570) Does that mean it's inaccessible? Or that he just can't find the name. Because my code does work...

Comment: I believe its working. I tried it and seems to be working for me after doing the change https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-gagarin-9zj05?file=/src/index.js
check it out and let me know.